# Sqlite Create new columns from column containing  ;

Tags: sqlite, substr

I have a database `test.db` with the first column containing `123456;abcdef;ghijk` etc. Is it possible to split the data into its own colums?

`123456` never changes length.

`abcdef` and `ghijk` change length and also may contain nothing.

I have tried the below string but i get the `;` appear in either `t2` or `t3` depending on the length of `abcdef` and `ghijk`.

```
select substr(column,1,6) AS "t1",
       substr(column,8,6) AS "t2",
       substr(column,15,10) AS "t3" test.db
```

Is the `;` seperator causing the issue?

Or can i output the database to `.sql`, format the txt then import to a new database?

Comment: If the length of these 'fields' are not fixed, using `substr` will not help.

Comment: Thankyou for replying. So this is not possible, Is there another way ?

Comment: What tools can you use outside of SQLite? What about Python?

Comment: Not familier with python

Answer (score 1):

There is no [built-in SQLite function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) that can split strings like this.

If your are using the SQLite C API or a wrapper like APSW, you could create your own function ([C](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), [APSW](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/connection.html#apsw.Connection.createscalarfunction)).

If you want to do nothing more than a one-time conversion, export/import through a text file would be the simplest solution.

Comment: What i am trying to do is get the ; removed give the data its own column then using sqlite php generator create a php page of the database for my website. I think it may be a bit to much for me as i am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your rows into columns by:

```
create table t1 as
select substr(c1,0,instr(c1,';')) as column1, 
       substr(c1,instr(c1,';')+1,instr(c1,';')-1) as column2,
       substr(c1,instr(c1,';')+1+instr(substr(c1,instr(c1,';')+1),';')) as column3
from table_test;
```

where c1 is the column you are selecting from.