# How to split comma delimited values into multiple rows using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python and SQLite to manipulate a database.

I have an SQLite Table `Movies` that looks like this:

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA, Germany, Mexico 
| 2              | Brazil, Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

I would like to split the comma delimited values in `Country` and insert them into **another table** `Countries` so that `Countries` table looks like this

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA
| 1              | Germany
| 1              | Mexico
| 2              | Brazil
| 2              | Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

How do I do split the values from `Country` column in `Movies` table and insert them into `Country` column in `Countries` table?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744155/sqlite-create-new-columns-from-column-containing), I can't accomplish this task using pure SQLite. How would I go about it using Python?

Comment: If the key to the table is `ID` then you obviously can't. BTW, please show some code, so that we have something to refer to your question with.

Comment: @barakmanos The `ID` column is not the primary key.

Comment: @CL.: Where exactly is that stated within the question?

Comment: @barakmanos In the example that shows duplicate values in this column. In a junction table like this, the primary key consists of both columns.

Comment: you can try `sqlalchemy` to extract each row then split the second coloumn and insert the data into the new table by simply iterating over it.

Comment: You don't need SQLAlchemy; this is trivial even with plain SQL.

Comment: @CL. Please make an example if the solution is trivial. Thx.

Comment: "Countries" implies the table is for storing information about countries. You probably want to call that MovieCountries or something to indicate it's a join table associating movies with countries. You'll also want to change "ID" to "MovieID" to indicate it's a foreign key of the associated Movie, not a primary key for the Country. It would also help people reading your question to reference [the answer which prompted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39691407/14660).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python,

```
cursor.execute("""Select * from Movies""")
all_data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Countries
                    (ID TEXT,
                    Country TEXT)""")
for single_data in all_data:
    countries = single_data[1].split()
    for single_country in countries:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Countries VALUES(%s,"%s")"""%(single_data[0],single_country))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: This code blows up when some name contains a quote. That link does not work in SQLite for an arbitrary number of values.

Comment: @the_prole : its not overwriting Movies table. It first creates Movies_2 table -> adding data as per requirement ->Deleting Movies table and Renaming Movies_2 to Movies

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. But in the question I specified that the data should be written to a separate table `Countries`. `Movies` should not be deleted... but I think you almost solved it.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to both quoting problems and a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid both problems, always [use bind parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Countries VALUES(:id,:name)", { "id": single_data[0], "name": single_country })`

Comment: Perfect thx .... only thing is I don't think I need the conn.commit() at the end of the inner loop. I can just call it at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in pure SQLite using a common table expression.

```
create table movies(id integer primary key, country text);
insert into movies values
(1,'USA, Germany, Mexico'), (2,'Brazil, Canada'), (3,'Peru');

create table countries(id integer, country text);
insert into countries
WITH split(id, country, str) AS (
    SELECT id, '', country||',' FROM movies
    UNION ALL SELECT id,
    trim(substr(str, 0, instr(str, ','))),
    substr(str, instr(str, ',')+1)
    FROM split WHERE str!=''
) SELECT id, country FROM split WHERE country!='' ORDER BY id;

SELECT * FROM countries;

id|country
1|USA
1|Germany
1|Mexico
2|Brazil
2|Canada
3|Peru
```